# Undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for the "ClassName" (parameter at index [0]) of the class

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, mutation

I'm creating an input type for nestJs graphQL mutation. After providing the Input type to my mutation argument I'm getting this error

[image]

**Input Type**

```
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsDate, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class MasterManagementCreateInput {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field(() => String)
  masterNumber: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field(() => String)
  flightNumber: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field(() => String)
  departureAirPort: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field(() => String)
  arrivalAirPort: string;

  @IsDate()
  @Field(() => Date, { nullable: true })
  DepartureTime: Date;

  @IsDate()
  @Field(() => Date, { nullable: true })
  arrivalTime: Date;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Field(() => String)
  deliveryStatus: string;
}
```

**Resolver**

```
import { Args, Query, Resolver, Mutation } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { MasterManagement } from './entities';
import { MasterManagementService } from './master-management.service';
import { FindById } from '../dtos';
import { MasterManagementUpdateInput, MasterManagementCreateInput } from './dto';

@Resolver(() => MasterManagement)
export class MasterManagementResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly masterManagementService: MasterManagementService,
  ) {}

  @Query(() => [MasterManagement])
  async allMasterManagement() {
    return await this.masterManagementService.getAll();
  }

  @Query(() => MasterManagement)
  async masterManagementById(@Args('id') id: FindById) {
    return await this.masterManagementService.getById({ id });
  }

  @Mutation(() => MasterManagement)
  async createMasterManagement(
    @Args('createInput')
    input: MasterManagementCreateInput,
  ) {
    return await this.masterManagementService.create(input);
  }

  @Mutation(() => MasterManagement)
  async updateMasterManagement(
    @Args('updateInput') input: MasterManagementUpdateInput,
  ) {
    const { id } = input;
    delete input.id;
    return await this.masterManagementService.update(input, { id });
  }
}
```

I don't know why this error is ocurring. I already used the same logic in my other resolvers and it is working fine. The itresting part is if I use an **@InputType**  from other resolvers in this resolver it works fine.